# Transmitting/Sending big packet safely using TcpClient/Socket

Tags: c#, .net, socket, tcp

I am writing a TCP based client that need to send and receive data. I have used the `Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)` provided for Socket class by the .NET Framework.

After being connected to the socket, I start waiting for data on the socket using `BeginReceive`.

Now, while I am waiting for the data on the Socket, I may need to send data over the socket. And the send method can be called multiple times,

So I have make sure that

- All the bytes from previous `Send` call is entirely sent.
- The way I am sending the Data is safe considering that, while a data send is in progress, any call to send data can be made.

**This is my first work on socket, So is my approach right to send data ?**

```
    private readonly object writeLock = new object();
    public void Send(NetworkCommand cmd)
    {
        var data = cmd.ToBytesWithLengthPrefix();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncDataSent, data);
    }

    private int bytesSent;
    private void AsyncDataSent(object odata)
    {
        lock (writeLock)
        {
            var data = (byte[])odata;
            int total = data.Length;
            bytesSent = 0;
            int buf = Globals.BUFFER_SIZE;
            while (bytesSent < total)
            {
                if (total - bytesSent < Globals.BUFFER_SIZE)
                {
                    buf = total - bytesSent;
                }
                IAsyncResult ar = socket.BeginSend(data, bytesSent, buf, SocketFlags.None, DataSentCallback, data);
                ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
```

How object is changed into `byte[]`, sometimes the `NetworkCommand` can be as big as **0.5 MB**

```
    public byte[] ToBytesWithLengthPrefix()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, this, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the asynchronous method `BeginSend()` when you immediately synchronously wait for it to complete? Why don't you just use `Send()`? Also, can you use C# 5.0?

Comment: no i am limited to .net 3.5, i have to use BeginSend as i am already awaiting for data to be received : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356507/transmitting-sending-big-packet-safely-using-tcpclient-socket/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `ToArray()` method of the `MemoryStream` you could use `GetBuffer()` instead because this isn't creating a new array.

Edit based on [@Iridium](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27497/iridium)'s [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/transmitting-sending-big-packet-safely-using-tcpclient-socket/113906?noredirect=1#comment211060_113906)

But this is only good if you use one of the constructor that creates a not resizable `MemoryStream` which isn't the case for the default constructor.

Calling `Dispose()` on the `MemoryStream` closes the `stream` too.

If you enclose the stream inside inside a `using` block the disposing of the stream will be handled automatically.

```
public byte[] ToBytesWithLengthPrefix()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, this, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

I needed to look twice at `var data = (byte[])odata;` which is a clear sign that you should make the method argument `odata` easier to distinguish from `data`, so `objectData` or `dataToSend` would be better.

`int buf` isn't well named either. One shouldn't use abbreviations to name variables. A much better name would be for instance `dataSize` or just `size` to indicate that it is the amount of data being sent.

Comment: The internal buffer returned by `GetBuffer()` may be larger than the stream's `Length`. Since the true length is not also returned, this could result in sending more data than expected (and more than indicated by the prefixed length indicator).